# Change cell color based on value of another cell

Tags: excel, vba, colors, find

I'm trying to run a code that upon pressing a button, finds a cell from a column ("H") in another sheet (labeled "MFG PNs") and matches its value with what is entered in cell "Z21" on my sheet labeled "SPC". Once the cell in H is found, I am trying to change the corresponding cell in column Q on the same row to a different color.

I am currently getting this error message: "Run time error 9, subscript out of range"
It occurs at the color changing part of the code.

```
Sub Approve_Click()

   Dim r As Long
    Dim m As Long
    m = Sheets("MFG PNs").Range("H3:H1200").Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    For r = 1 To m
        If Sheets("MFG PNs").Range("H" & r) = Sheets("SPC").Range("Z21") Then
            Sheets("MFG PNs").Range("Q" & r).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(0, 97, 0)
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color indexes are values that go from 1 to 56 (see below) RGB color values are usually quite a bit larger than this.

You can change .ColorIndex to .Color and enter an appropriate color, or change the RGB(0,97,0) to a specific index value.

VBA code is available **[here](http://www.databison.com/index.php/excel-color-palette-and-color-index-change-using-vba/)** that generates color indexes and value on a worksheet.

[image: Color Index]

Comment: Thank you! That was a very simple fix. Haha

Answer (score 0):

While testing your code, I did find another problem: it crashes when the target string ("*") is not found. The correction below should account for that:

```
    Set cell = Sheets("MFG PNs").Range("H3:H1200").Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    If (Not cell Is Nothing) Then
       For r = 1 To cell.Row
        'YOUR CODE
       Next r
    End If
```